# Как правильно записать переменную типа (void*)i в массив char* как целую?

Tags: linux, c, указатели

У меня есть целая переменная:

```
int i;
```

Для того, чтобы мне ее подать в функцию, нужно привести ее к типу `void*`.

```
void my_function((void *)i);
```

Другая функция (`void *my_function2()`) может вернуть это значение с тем же типом void*.

Но потом мне требуется записать это значение в массив `char *buffer` именно как целое число:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d", SOMETHING);
```

Если `SOMETHING` будет `(int*)i`, то есть `sprintf(buffer, "%d", (int*)i);`, то форматная печать выдаст нужный результат `printf("%s\n", buffer)`.

Но ведь, чтобы получить целое значение, я считаю, нужно, чтобы SOMETHING было `*(int*)i`; то есть `sprintf(buffer, "%d", *(int*)i);`

Но в этом случае форматная печать выдаст 0.
Укажите пожалуйста на мою ошибку.

**Update:**
Минимальный пример:

```
int i = 5;
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(10);
my_function((void *)i);
sprintf(buffer, "%d", *(int*)my_function2());
printf("%s\n", buffer);
0
```

**Этот пример работает правильно:**

```
int i = 5;
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(10);
my_function((void *)i);
sprintf(buffer, "%d", (int*)my_function2());
printf("%s\n", buffer);
5
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37060/discussion-on-question-by-maxim-gusev------vo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете из функции значение `int`, преобразованное в `void*`. Именно значение, а не указатель на него! Значит, и преобразовывать его нужно в значение, а не в указатель:

```
sprint(buffer,"%d",(int)my_function2());
```

То, что вы получили верный ответ при `(int*)` - ничего не меняет: вы передали в функцию `sprintf` **возвращенное значение**, а `%d` сам преобразовал его в `int`.

А вот когда вы пишете `*(int*)...` - вы **разыменовываете** указатель, в который превращено целое значение. И вам так уж везет (или не везет - как посмотреть...), что не происходит краха программы при обращении к некорректному адресу (это было бы лучшим результатом), а возвращается значение, там находящееся...